# Where is redis server socket created?

Tags: sockets, tcp, redis

I've been studying redis source code. I see that main() (in redis.c)calls initServer() which calls aeCreateEventLoop(), which again calls aeApiCreate(). aeApiCreate() creates an epoll instance. Control returns to main() and then it listens for connections. Where are socket and bind system calls called? I dont see where the socket is created for server.

Answer (score 0):

In redis.c, main() calls initServer() which calls anetUnixServer() (defined in anet.c). This calls anetCreateSocket() to create a server socket. :)